# How to plot Total Return?

Tags: reactjs, plot, finance, recharts

I'm looking at various libraries to see how I can plot the total return of a stock within the time period specified. The algorithm is simply (data - dataMin / dataMax ) * 100 for the % return across the time period. I'm currently using recharts but it seems like there's a limitation in their library as I cannot alter the Y Axis to plot that number AND the price at the time the mouse is hovering over.

Thanks!

Edit:
I have something like this at the moment but as you can see, the Y Axis scaling is capped at ~1000% whereas the max should be ~2800%. https://codesandbox.io/s/recharts-issue-template-czf5t

Comment: What language and tools are you looking to do this with?

Comment: I'm using ReactJS. Just looking for any tool library that could support this or is good for plotting financial data. I'm currently using recharts but am looking for something else if possible.